# Find average weight of a box when picked from a bag consisting of 50 boxes of different colors

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let's say we randomly pick a box from a bag of boxes with outer surfaces colored into three: WHITE, RED, and BLUE.

What is unknown?

Number of WHITE, RED, or BLUE boxes in the bag.

What is known?

Average weight of a box with surface colored WHITE: 52

Average weight of a box with surface colored RED: 24

Average weight of a box with surface colored BLUE: 36

Is it correct to say that the average weight of a box picked at random from the bag

= (1/3)*54 + (1/3)*24 + (1/3)*36

= 38

Edit: If there is an equal change of getting a 'WHITE','RED' and 'BLUE' color ball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect. If there are a different number of boxes of each colour, then the probability of selecting that colour will be different. For example, if there were $47$ white boxes, $2$ red boxes and $1$ blue box, the probability of selecting a white box will be $\frac{47}{50}$ while the probability of selecting a blue box will only be $\frac{1}{50}$.

The average weight that you desire to compute is equivalent to finding the expected value of a random variable $X$ where $X$ can take the value of $52, 24$ or $36$. Considering there to be $a$ white boxes, $b$ red boxes and $c$ blue boxes, we can compute $E[X]$ as follows:

\begin{align}
E[X] &= P(X = 52) \times 52 + P(X =24) \times 24 + P(X = 36) \times 36\\
&=\frac{52a}{50} + \frac{24b}{50} + \frac{36c}{50}\\
&= \frac{26a + 12b + 18c}{25}\\
& = \frac{26a + 12b + 18(50-a-b)}{25}\\
&= \frac{2(4a - 3b + 450)}{25}
\end{align}

Hence, to compute the average (i.e. $E[X]$), it is necessary to know the quantity of at least $2$ colours of the boxes.

Comment: What if there is an equal chance that it could be 'white', 'blue' or 'red'? Then is it correct?

Comment: @vp_050 If that were possible, you would be correct. However, unless there’s some asymmetry between the choices, that’s impossible in this case as $50/3$ is not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

No, of course not. If you don't know the number of each kind of box in the bag they might all be white. All you can know is that the average weight is somewhere between 24 and 52.

If you had to make an *estimate* you could use your calculation, specifically noting that it was based on the *assumption* that there were the same number of boxes of each kind.

Or you could pick a number of boxes at random and calculate the average weight of those. The larger the sample the better an estimate.